# How to check existence of an embedded resource image before showing it in a pictureox

Tags: c#, forms, resources

I have the image test.png in the resources. I want to test if that image exists and if it does show it in a picturebox. I read a lot of the existing articles but can't figure out how to do this??

The code below is very wrong and appreciate your help to point me in the right direction.

using System.Reflection;

namespace GetResource
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] resNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
        foreach (string resName in resNames)
        {
            if (resName == "test.png")
                pictureBox1.Image = resName;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The following class is a container for remembering resources in a project of type Bitmap and Icon.

`using System.Drawing;`

Container

```
public class ResourceItem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Resource name
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Image which is either an icon or bitmap
    /// </summary>
    public Bitmap Image { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates if dealing with an icon so when displaying the
    /// control used to display can adjust it's size or Size mode
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsIcon { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

Class to read into a List of `ResourceItem` each image name, is Icon and the image.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
// change ChangeImage with your namespace
using ChangeImage.Properties;

namespace ChangeImage.Classes
{
    public class ImageHelper
    {

        public static List<ResourceItem> ResourceItemList()
        {
            var items = new List<ResourceItem>();

            foreach (var name in ResourceImageNames())
            {
                
                var item = new ResourceItem() {Name = name, IsIcon = false};
                
                if (Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(name) is Icon)
                {
                    item.Image  = ((Icon)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(name))?.ToBitmap();
                    item.IsIcon = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Image = (Bitmap)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(name);
                }
                
                items.Add(item);


            }

            return items;
            
        }
        public static List<string> ResourceImageNames()
        {

            try
            {
                var names = new List<string>();
                var resourceSet = Resources.ResourceManager
                    .GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, 
                        true, true);
                names.AddRange(
                    from DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in resourceSet 
                    where dictionaryEntry.Value is Image || dictionaryEntry.Value is Icon 
                    select dictionaryEntry.Key.ToString());
                return names;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following shows the images in the current project

[image]

How to use

```
private void NamesInResourceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var resources = ImageHelper.ResourceItemList();
    var imageItem = resources.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Chat");
    if (imageItem is not null)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = imageItem.Image;
    }
}
```

Resources in the project used.

[image]