# Handling resources when migrating from old style csproj to sdk csproj

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, csproj

I'm trying to migrate from an old style csproj file where I have this in the file

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Resources\CustomerLogo.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

and when I, in my code, calls:

```
var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(assembly.GetName().Name + ".g", assembly);
var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
var resourceSet = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(culture, true, true);
```

I can find the file in the `resourceSet` with `Resources\CustomerLogo.png` as key and a stream as value.

I have now tried converting the csproj file, and it still includes the ItemGroup, but now it does not appear in the resourceSet.

Any that can help me?

Yours
/peter

Comment: Have you tried creating a test project in the new SDK format on the side, manually adding the resource and to it and then looking the .csproj file to see what changed?  When I was converting old projects a couple of years ago, I found that manually rebuilding a new one from scratch using the IDE (with the old one alongside it for reference) worked much better

Comment: The following was done .net5 [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73917111/5509738)